# Implementing fail/safe method while writing file into SD card

Tags: c

I need a help/guide regarding the file writing in SD card. I am writing a file into SD card interfaced with TI CC3200 controller which is using FAT FS. The use case is like that, during file write if power is loss, then my data should not corrupt or I can have some mechanism to identify corrupt data in file.

There are few options in my mind like implementation of CRC, checksum but it costs controller performance.

So to identify that I need a mechanism that can be implemented through coding. I want to know is there any available method or something from where I can start to implement to identify corrupt data.

Comment: Yes, such methods exist, and you’ve already named them: checksums, in particular CRC. You might also want to read up on error-correcting codes (as opposed to error-*detecting* codes, which the above are). Yes, they cost controller performance but c’est la vie.

Comment: Are power cuts the only potential risk? when if ever is this data transferred? does the controller need to do the detection/correction? does the controller ever require the data to perform needed tasks? for a generic solution there's no way out of the cost, but with a custom tailored solution you might be able to substantially decrease them.

Comment: Switch from FAT FS to filesystems that implements copy-on-write guarantees, ex. [littlefs](https://github.com/ARMmbed/littlefs).

Comment: Doesn’t FAT FS already have CRC?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph ohkay is there any reference work I can refer? Or any other reference you want to share?

Comment: @KamilCuk, Great thanks for sharing this, it might be helpful

Comment: @Marichyasana, till now I haven't seen. Do you have any reference ?

Comment: @sam1006 "AN-413 Disk Interface Design Guide and Users Manual" by Texas Instruments. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa710/snoa710.pdf

Comment: @sam1006 Actually the CRC is part of the physical layer to the device and is not related to FAT directly, it would be the same for other formats like NTFS. In fact some Linux system allow NTFS in one partition and the standard Linux FS in another, and can read both.

Comment: @Marichyasana, ya but it can be implemented like littleFS suggested by kamilCuk

Comment: @sam1006 that would mean you are doing the crc twice; but the extra time is negligible so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Marichyasana you mean it is already implemented on the driver level? But if it is the case then why I am facing data corruption during file write

Comment: @sam1006 Look at the doc I linked for you. It is implemented in the firmware. Just because there is a CRC it doesn't mean that errors cannot occur, it is just a matter of detecting that an error occurred or not.

Comment: @Marichyasana Yes you are right. Thank you for your suggestions